# How to show data from Db in formio multiselect

Tags: c#, asp.net, multi-select, formio

You can see the formio multiselect example in fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/nexawo/aqxLwuoc/1/

In this you can add multiple values and submit it which will save the data but when we get the data from db and want to make it selcted items it show [object Object] instread of data

I am using formio multi select which is working fine for inserting and updating data but it doesn't show the saved value from Db.

```
public class Students
{
public int? StudentId{get; set;}
public string StudentName{get; set;}
}
```

```
public readonly List<studentDto>;
```

I am showing the student name as a label and saving id in DB. In formio multi-select, I give property name studentDto when I submit the data I get data in this form

```
studentDto: {
0: {StudentId: 1, StudentName:"John"}
1: {StudentId: 2, StudentName:"Smith"}
}
```

This data save in Db perfectly

Now I want when users come to the index page there they can see these record as the selected value in multi-select Column but when I visit the page I see the data in this form [object Object]

So how can I show these two records as selected values.

Answer (score 0):

if your multi select as example is a listbox, you can from below code

```
int i=0;
foreach (var item in studentDto)
 {            
   ListBox1.Items[i].Value = item.StudentId.Tostring();
   ListBox1.Items[i].Text=item.StudentName.Tostring();
   i++;
 }
```

Comment: As I told I am using form.io multi-select and there is no such option where I can add this code